# How to pass radio button value to img link in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to pass the radio button value to Javascript instead of the whole img link but no image is being display. If I pass the whole image link to Javascript the image is able to show in the display.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':radio').change(function (e) {
        //clear the div
        $('#display').html('');
        //update the div
        $(':radio:checked').each(function (ind, ele) {
            $('#display').html('<img src="/images/"') + val() + '.png">');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="motor_1"><img src="/images/motor_1.png" width="150px" height="150px">
```

Comment: so is the goal to check if the radio button is checked or to display the image when it is check? If we have the element and it is a radio button `ele.checked` should return `true` when checked.

Comment: @jmp the goal is to display the image when it is checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @jmp the goal is to display the image when it is checked

In general, this code would display an `img` element when it is clicked

**Code**

```
<style>img{ display: none}</style>
<input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="motor_1">
<img src="https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2018/11/24/16/cat.jpg" >
<script>
(async () => {
    let radioBtn = document.querySelector("body > input[name=vehicle]");
    radioBtn.onclick = (event) => {
        if (radioBtn && radioBtn.checked) {
            let img = document.querySelector('img');
            img.style.display = 'inherit';
        }
    }
})();
</script>
```

In this case, it would seem we want to parameterize the `src` string. Does this answer the question? I used the reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62853517/112233

**code**

```js
$('#display').html(`<img src="/images/${ele.value}.png">`);
```

assuming the `ele` is the radio button element.

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery `val()` method instead of just calling `val()` you want:

```
$(this).val()
```

Or the native element property:

```
this.value
```